# Does the MSI V Class motherboard support AMD Phenom™ II X4?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, amd-phenom

Recently (in the last year) I have configured and upgraded my system.

- **Motherboard:** MSI V class
- **Processor:** AMD X2 4000+
- **HDD:** 160 GB

Now I would like to upgrade the processor.

- Will an *AMD Phenom™ II X4* fit into my *v class* motherboard?
- Which is the latest/faster Processor of AMD? (AMD Turion™ X2 or AMD Phenom™ II X4)
- Which would be preferable for Desktop/laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never heard of a V class motherboard and can't quickly find it on Google.

Anyway, After looking it up for you, the AMD X2 4000+ cpu requires AM2 based motherboard and the AMD Phenom II X4 requires a AM3 based socket motherboard.

So, sorry, These will not work together.